# How can I bake the cloth simulation into keyframed vertices or shape keyed vertices?

Tags: cloth-simulation, baking

I'm simulating a cloth. How can I bake the cloth simulation into keyframed vertices or shape keyed vertices?

Answer (score 9):

If you look in the Modifiers section of the properties you will see an Apply button (you probably don't want that one) and an Apply as Shape Key button.  That's the one you want.

After you have turned the cloth shape into a Shape Key, you will have to go to the mesh section and dial up the influence of the new Cloth shape key to 1.0 to change the cloth into the shape that you "baked".

Comment: Just a note since I was having a devil of a time finding it: In Blender 2.9, the buttons for applying a modifier are in the drop-down to the right of its view toggle buttons.

Answer (score 9):

If you want a single frame, see Mutant Bob's answer. If you want the entire cache, select your cloth object and export it as an .mdd or .pc2. You can then bring this cache back in using the Mesh Cache modifier, or you can import it as a series of shapekeys (1 for each frame.)

Comment: This is what I want :D So indeed bake the entire cache, but how can I export my object as .mdd or .pc2?

Comment: File > Export > Lightwave Point Cache (.mdd.) If the option isn't there, enable the addon under preferences > addons. But it should be on by default. I'm not sure if that exporter does the selected object, or all visible objects. If you try to import it and you get a vertex count mismatch, it's probably the second. In that case, you can isolate it by putting that object on it's own layer and turning off the other layers.

Comment: @Drudge Hello! I'm looking for a way to convert the cloth simulation in my scene into shapekeys animation, in order to transfer it from Blender to Maya and other 3D editors. Could you describe this process in more detail, please?

Comment: @Drudge How can I import .mdd or .pc2 as a series of shapekeys? And how can I save the result as FBX or other format, suitable for other 3D editors like Maya?

Comment: Select your object, then go to File -> Import -> Lightwave Point Cache (.mdd). If you don't see it there, go to User Prefs and enable it under Addons. To save as FBX, File -> Export FBX

Comment: also, you can import .pc2 to shapekeys with this wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/… ("import as file" from user preferences > addons), you'll get a shapekey for every frame, already animated: edit as you like

Comment: @Drudge Thank you for explanation! Unfortunately, I have problems when using .mdd. I describe them here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42910/how-to-bake-object-with-cloth-simulation-and-subsurf-not-applied-having-troub  
There I ask the question of how to bake cloth simulation, as well as apply subsurf to the result, but also I describe there a problem that I encountered after importing .mdd of a simple object with a cloth simulation (without subsurf), maybe you know how to fix this problem?

Comment: @m.ardito Thank you! I had problems when I used .mdd. I describe them here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42910/how-to-bake-object-with-cloth-simulation-and-subsurf-not-applied-having-troub  I want to try .pc2, maybe it will work. I activated the addon, but now I can export in .pc2 format, but the option to import .pc2 does not appears. How can I turn it on? And could you please send the link again, the link in the previous message is leading to a nonexistent page. Thank you!

Comment: @Maxim sorry to be late, that link was truncated pasting it, here it is  working (hopefully) http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Import-Export/PC2_Pointcache_import (I tried this and it worked)

Comment: @m.ardito Thank you! I downloaded the script and put into Blender add-ons folder, but I cant find it in the list of add-ons in the user preferences, even after restarting Blender. Sorry for such a question, but I almost never worked with Github, to download the file I used the RMB - "save file as" option, and received the io_import_pc2.py file. Is it the correct way to download the script or in this case, the script is downloaded incorrectly?

Comment: @m.ardito By the way, here I discuss the process of baking cloth simulation: http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?387794-How-to-transfer-Blender-scene-with-cloth-simulation-to-Maya-and-Houdini  I still have some problems, and I added a simplified version of my scene in my last post in that topic. If you will have any ideas - I will be very grateful for your advice.

Comment: @Maxim as I said above, you should "import as file" from user preferences > addons

Comment: @m.ardito I tried this way too. And there were no error messages, so it seems that the import was successful. But I don't see this addon among other add-ons, and the option to import pc2 not available. http://postimg.org/image/w9i9ztde7/

Comment: Just to add yet another reference on this subject, there is tutorial about it: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=roRaaG_D9d8

Answer (score 2):

There is an alternate way which seemed easier for me, as I only needed 2 shapes. (I tried some other methods first.)
1. Simulate your cloth and bake as desired.
2. Duplicate the cloth mesh, move it slightly above. Remove cloth simulation, shape keys, ... to get just a plain mesh.
3. On the timeline, go to the frame you want for the cloth shape.
4. Select the duplicate cloth and add a Shrinkwrap modifier. Shrink to the original with the shape. For example, "project negative Z". Fine-tune until it looks right.
5. Apply the Shrinkwrap modifier as a shape key to the copy. It will be removed from the stack. You can test it by turning up the influence of the shape key.
6. On the timeline, go to another frame with a cloth shape you want.
7. Repeat 4 and 5 as many times as needed.