# How to convert cloth simulation into mesh animation?

Tags: animation, file-format, baking, cloth-simulation

I want to transfer Blender scene with cloth simulation to Maya and Houdini.

The solution of this problem involves answers to two questions:
- How to "bake" the animation, so it does not depend on the cloth modifier (how to bake cloth simulation into shape key animation, if this is what I need to do)?
- In what format it is better to save the final result for future transfer to Maya (fbx?)?

Comment: You can bake it as shape keys, in the modifier created by cloth. see related http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38427/how-can-i-bake-the-cloth-simulation-into-keyframed-vertices-or-shape-keyed-verti?rq=1

Comment: @m.ardito Thank you! As I understand the Drudge's answer, I can import the cache, using the Mesh Cache modifier (that does not fit in my case, because I need to be able to use animation in other editors, which do not have these modifiers) or "import it as a series of shapekeys (1 for each frame.)" - this seems to be what I need, could you please explain in more detail how to do it?

Comment: @m.ardito How can I import .mdd or .pc2 as a series of shapekeys? And how can I save the result as FBX or other format, suitable for other 3D editors like Maya?

Comment: I can't add an answer now that the question is closed as duplicate, but you can use the addon "export point cache" (just enable it) to a .pc2 file. Then use this http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Import-Export/PC2_Pointcache_import ("import as file" from user preferences > addons), you'll get a shapekey for every frame, already animated: edit as you like. For fbx and other programs, I don't know, never used them (and a little off topic maybe)

Comment: @m.ardito Thank you very much for the detailed answer! Well, my main question is "how to transfer Blender scene with cloth simulation from Blender into Maya", so the questions "how to bake the animation" and "what format to choose" - is parts of the main question :) But I can ask the second question separately, no problem. :)