# How to bake object with cloth simulation and subsurf (not applied)? Having trouble using .mdd method

Tags: animation, mesh, modifiers, cloth-simulation, shape-keys

I need to transfer Blender scene with cloth simulation to Maya and Houdini.

In addition to cloth simulation, I used subsurf (not applied), after cloth modifer. And if I apply the subsurf, the cloth simulation will change, while I need to export to Maya an object with exactly the same animation that I have now.

[image]

I have used this method to export .mdd: http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?387461-Bake-Cloth-to-game-engine

and I faced a few problems in the process. I used a simple plane with cloth sim to demonstrate them:

- 1) If I export .mdd of an object with a cloth simulation but WITHOUT
  subsurf, and then, after export, remove the cloth simulation and
  import .mdd - everything is OK, but the object increases in size:

Before importing .mdd:
[image]

After removing cloth sim and importing .mdd:
[image]

- 2) If I export .mdd of an object with a cloth simulation AND WITH
  subsurf (not applied), and then, after export, remove only
  clothsimulation and import .mdd - I get a highly distorted object.
  And even if, after export, I remove them both - cloth simulation and
  subsurf, and then import .mdd - the result is the same:

I exported as .mdd this model with cloth sim and subsurf (not applied):
[image]

This is what I get after removing cloth sim and importing .mdd:[image]

And the same result, if i remove both, cloth sim and subsurf before importing .mdd:
[image]

- 3) And the third problem is that I can't apply subsurf to the object
  with the shape keys, so even if I did not have those problems, which
  I wrote above, I could not apply subsurf thereafter.

[image]

How can I fix these errors? I really need to export my work to Maya.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: @MrZak I need to send this model to people who continue to work with it in Maya. I have already demonstrated them pre-render, but now they need the model itself, with all the dynamics (because it is a clothes, hanging on a rope in the wind).

The main problem now - how to apply subsurf modifer after I bake the animation in shape kays.

Comment: Some time ago I heard about using .mdd exporter in Maya to import/export animation and .pc2 plug-in in Blender to convert it to Maya's cache - http://tea3d.blogspot.com/2013/02/tranfer-animation-between-blender-and.html. I'm not sure how it works now though.

Comment: @MrZak Thank you! I used this method, and faced those problems when using it, but I already have found a solution. Thank you for the link!

Comment: If you found a solution please add an answer to your question so others facing this problem would benefit from your knowledge.

Comment: @MrZak Of course, I'll add an answer as soon as check that it works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Enable the .mdd file importer / exporter addon:
   [image]
2. Select an object with the cloth simulation and subsurf (not applied). CTRL + A - apply rotation, scale and location. Note that if some other objects, which are parented (or vertex parented) to that object, after applying operation, they may change their position and rotation. To avoid it, unparent them (ALT + P - Clear Parent), before applying, then apply rotation, scale and position, and then parent them back.
3. While the object with ththe cloth simulation is selected, export the .mdd file. Export may take some time.
4. After  export - remove the Cloth simulation.
5. Unparent (ALT + P - Clear Parent).
6. Apply subsurf.
7. At this stage, I usially re-applying rotation, scale and position, just in case - (CTRL + A).
8. While the object is still selected - import .mdd file.

Play the animation, or select a different current frame to update the final result. Note that the shape key animation rather increases the size of the project.

---

*Many thanks to  **Mr Zak**, **m.ardito** from `blender.stackexchange.com` and to **Richard Marklew**, **benu** from `blenderartists.org` for their help in finding solution!*

Comment: About 6. Apply subsurf: if not applied, the mesh deformation DO shows up in the viewport but WON'T be rendered. Maybe you could edit your answer to specify that ?