# Export geometry nodes to FBX

Tags: export, geometry-nodes, .fbx, gltf

We have made a animation using geometry-nodes and want to use this in an AR setting. For this we need a FBX or GLTF file.

Is there anyway to export a file like this without losing the modifiers?

Comment: No you can't. It's all blender specific. Read more on this thread https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/93444/is-it-possible-to-export-object-from-blender-with-modifiers-and-use-them-in-exte

Comment: okay thankyou!!