# sail wind animation from Blender to Unity

Tags: animation

I created a raft with a sail and I added a WindForce in order to animate it.
As I'm really happy with the result (cloth modifier + WindForce), I would like to import the result to Unity.

But as it's not a standard animation with rigs and stuff, I have no idea how to export it, if it's even possible.

In case it's not, I was thinking about reproducing every frames of the Sail wind animation, but the question is :

It is possible to "extract" or "copy" a frame in order to create an independant object with the same shape?

I hope it's clear and not too stricky to solve!
Thanks for reading and any help will be well appreciated.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42910/how-to-bake-object-with-cloth-simulation-and-subsurf-not-applied-having-troub