# How to export a simple waves animation as FBX file?

Tags: export, .fbx

I want to export a little animated wave model I made in Blender, so I can upload it on my website as an animated interactive model. I am a beginner.

[image]

I added a 50x50 plane and then, used the subdivision surface modifier to divide it into the max number of squares as possible. Then I added two wave modifiers on the plane so they interfere. Then I just added the colours from the "shading" section. So the parts where the waves interfere is shown as red. That is everything I did.

I read [this tutorial](https://help.sansar.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002888226-3D-model-export-and-setup-tips-using-popular-3D-tools-#3D-model%C2%A0export-using-Blender) to export my model as an FBX

1. Select the object or objects you want to export.
2. Choose File > Export > FBX (.fbx).
3. From the Export window, expand the Export FBX panel on the left
   side.
4. On the Main tab, check the box for Selected Objects.
5. On the Main tab, press the Mesh button.
6. Click the Geometries tab.
7. Check the box for Tangent Space.
8. Press the Export FBX button.

But when I view my 3D model with the build-in 3D model viewer in windows, all I see is this:

[image]

The animation (i.e if I play nothing happens) and the shading don't appear in the settings. All I see is a single frame and no colours, I can move the 3D model though. What should I do?
How do I export this as a proper animated 3D model FBX file?

Comment: You need cache to play vertex animation. FBX alone doesn't have it. Consider baking .pc2 cache, but this depends on whether your viewing app supports it.

Comment: @SergeL How to do you cache? I am like the beginner of beginners, is there any tutorial you can link?

Comment: You have to export the cache as mdd then reimport it, which will create shapekeys what you can export in fbx. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42910/how-to-bake-object-with-cloth-simulation-and-subsurf-not-applied-having-troub