# Umbrella animation, cloth penetration

Tags: animation, cloth-simulation

I'm triyng to animate an umbrella like a folding fan, i've hooked the cloth to the rods, it follows the rods and makes good folds after the solidify and subdivision modifiers, but the cloth is penetrated by the rods. I don't know how to solve this problem.. i've tried to change some physics value but the bake always went bad.
Images https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1R75.jpg

Comment: Thats a challenge :) When comes to collision with thin collider ... try to add two extra lines (loops) from sides of each rood and weight paint to red ... probably better to share your file via https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com so we can check what you already tried. And please attack your images into your Q via edit. Don't use external links. Thank you

Comment: Some general tips: the quads in the topology should be as close to squares as possible. Adding extra geometry (subdividing) helps. Adding extra simulation steps helps (the idea is that the more steps per frame, the less likely something is to have enough speed to teleport across a collision barrier and get stuck, or to collide so deeply that the bounce is very fast). This of course increases simulation time.

Answer (score 0):

I have been having the same problem, and already spend some nights of the last week on this. The best solution i found was to export and import the cloth simulation as described in this link. After that i put the fabric a little bit higher so that it doesn't collide anymore.

It is the best thing i come up with, but i hope someone comes with a better solution.

[How can I bake the cloth simulation into keyframed vertices or shape keyed vertices?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38427/how-can-i-bake-the-cloth-simulation-into-keyframed-vertices-or-shape-keyed-verti)